# Django - define template includes/extends in one place in the same way url paths are defined in urls.py?

Tags: django, templates, django-urls

I'm really enjoying the transition from PHP to Python/Django and the ability to extend templates. However, I'm still finding that I'm still doing a fair bit of repetitive work in defining templates and extending other templates, etc. Just wondering if anyone knows of any way to abstract all this out into one file which tells which templates other templates should extend/include?

Comment: I think you mean just extend as includes are used in specific places in the template. hat would be impossible to do. The extends would be **near** impossible also.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, not with the default functionality.  Abstracting things like the `{% base %}` tag to another file would make the templates much harder to read.

One way to remove the "extra work" is to make your editor do it for you.  In my case, I define all of my templates as `.dhtml` files and have VIM paste in a template into the file whenever I open an empty `.dhtml` file.  Most programming-centric editors have this functionality built in to prevent you from having to manually copy/paste or retype your basic structures.

Another thing to consider is that you may be building the templates themselves in a less-than-optimal way.  For example, if you have different base templates, could you replace the different base templates with CSS?  CSS can change templates in ways that programmers can sometimes overlook.  For a good example, check out the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).  The changes you see are amazing, and they do not change the base HTML at all.

For a change like this, you could simply have this in `templates/base.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/default.css" />
{% block extracss %}{% endblock %}
```

And in order to include an over-riding CSS, you place this in your templates:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extracss %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/orchid_beauty.css" />
{% endblock %}
```